# Bidirectional half-duplex communication between PIC16 and an FPGA over a single copper track

Tags: pic, fpga, digital-communications

I need to implement a bidirectional communication mechanism between a PIC16LF microcontroller and an FPGA. It shall be used to transmit only a few kilo bits of data at most per second. The PCB cannot be changed now and I only have one spare pin that I can extend the functionality of.

Is it possible to implement a mechanism whereby just one copper track is used for bidirectional half-duplex communication between the two? I believe that if I do this, I shall have to implement some type of bit banging on the side of the PIC. The PIC shall be in charge and can poll the FPGA to see if it has any data.

Is there a well known example of this mechanism can work so I don't have to design the whole thing from scratch? Unfortunately, I cannot use SPI that would have solved all the problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as both the PIC and FPGA support tri-state buffers (i.e. can make them Hi-z) which is highly likely, then yes, you can easily do half-duplex with a single wire.

The safest way is to use open-drain outputs whereby each device only drives a logic 0 or releases the pin to hi-z, that way you can never have bus contention. A resistor is then used to pull high. If one or both devices have built-in pull-up resistors you can enable, that would save having to bodge a resistor onto the board.

If you don't have usable pull-ups, you would have to have some arbitration (e.g. master-slave) to make sure that both devices don't talk at the same time. When a device isn't talking it sets its pin as Hi-z, while the other drives high and low.

There are examples of fully formed single wire comms, such as [1-Wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire) which can perform bidirectional comms at 16kb/s.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement bi-directional communications over just one wire.

If you can find a ready made 1-wire implementation for your FPGA that could be a solution. A complete implementation could be complex as the 1-wire protocol is a multi drop topology that supports multiple slaves and device enumeration.

Consider using an asynchronous UART transport stream with a 10-bit data frame (Start, 8-data, Stop).

If possible use a 1K ohm resistor between the PIC and the FPGA. Should this not be possible then by all means configure the outputs to be open-drain and enable the weak pull-up in the PIC and FPGA.

You should be able to find a simplex UART implementation for your FPGA available from whoever makes your FPGA device.

The system oscillator of the PIC will determine the maximum achievable bit rate. For most PIC16F controllers a bit-bang UART that can send and receive can be implemented in firmware that requires about 10 instruction cycles per bit. This means that the transport speed could be up to 500K bits per second. Try for 10K to 100K bits per second so the signal integrity will be better.

Comment: The PIC is quite basic and all the current firmware is written in assembly language.